# How to identify binlog_format for a specific query?

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, master-slave-replication, binlog

I have `binlog_format` set to **MIXED** and it states that mariadb will decide whether to use **ROW** or **STATEMENT** based logging for each query. Where can I see that information for a specific query?

Comment: Please explain _why_ you need this feature.  There may be a cleaner workaround.

Comment: @RickJames I'm trying to optimize queries to use STATEMENT based replication if possible, thus I need to see what it will use. I'm creating a procedure that uses JSON_TABLE, but it states that it is unsafe for STATEMENT replication.

Comment: Is the Procedure being performed on both the Primary and Replica?  Does the proc have any DDL statements (eg, Insert)?  Are you sure that "JSON_TABLE" is what it is complaining about?

Answer (score 0):

If you:

`SET STATEMENT binlog_format=STATEMENT FOR {query}`
then:
`SHOW WARNINGS`

If you get an unsafe for replication error/warning, then `ROW` format will be used (per [mixed logging](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/binary-log-formats/#mixed-logging)).

[This page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/unsafe-statements-for-statement-based-replication/#unsafe-statements) contains a list of unsafe statements/functions for statement based replication.